# Vectorizing a raster containing holes using rasterio

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, rioxarray, geocube

I want to vectorize raster that contains holes (nodata) in the areas with valid data.
My current version uses rasterio.features.shapes:

```py
    shape_list = list(shapes(raster.values, mask=raster.values != raster.rio.nodata,
                             connectivity=_connectivity, transform=raster.rio.transform()))
    # convert the coordinates from pixel index  to offset in crs
    new_dict = {'geometry': [Polygon(x[0]['coordinates'][0]) for x in shape_list],
                'class': [x[1] for x in shape_list]}

    gdf = GeoDataFrame(new_dict, crs=raster.rio.crs)
```

I wrote the vectorized raster to file and found, that polygons does not contain holes (iterior is empty), where the raster has nodata values. Is there a way to fix it or another way of intersecting, that does not create this problem?

Comment: with only a quick look, you are only grabbing the first element here `x[0]['coordinates'][0]` where you might want to look into getting all coordinates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to use [`shapely.geometry.shape()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.shape) instead of trying to parse the coordinates yourself.

E.g:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes
from shapely.geometry import shape

from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from pandas import DataFrame


with rasterio.open('test.tif') as src:
    data = src.read(1, masked=True)

    # Use a generator instead of a list
    shape_gen = ((shape(s), v) for s, v in shapes(data, transform=src.transform))

    # either build a pd.DataFrame
    # df = DataFrame(shape_gen, columns=['geometry', 'class'])
    # gdf = GeoDataFrame(df["class"], geometry=df.geometry, crs=src.crs)

    # or build a dict from unpacked shapes
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(dict(zip(["geometry", "class"], zip(*shape_gen))), crs=src.crs)
```

[image]

Comment: Why using a generator? I often read there are saving CPU time and ram, but at least I have never found any benefits, when I tried them.  Perhaps it was to small, or I dit something wrong?

Comment: It's a good practice and it makes a difference when your data is large. Instead of reading all of it into a list then copying that list into a dataframe (thus taking up twice the memory), each element is only accessed once, when it's being added to the dataframe.

Comment: I get "Mask must have same shape as image". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You could use `shapes` as per my answer. Alternatively, as you're using `dataset_features` (which isn't used in my answer), you should specify a band index (`bidx` arg).

Answer (score 4):

With geocube 0.4+:

```py
import rioxarray
from geocube.vector import vectorize

data = rioxarray.open_rasterio("test.tif", mask_and_scale=True).squeeze()
data.name = "class"
gdf = vectorize(data)
```